# Take all the IP Addresses of given range into SQL Server Table

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2012

I have IP Addresses like '255.255.120.110-255.255.120.115,255.10.120.110-255.10.120.115,255.10.10.115'

I want to insert into table. Finally I need the result like below:

```
   IPAddresses
    ---------------
    255.255.120.110
    255.255.120.111
    255.255.120.112
    255.255.120.113
    255.255.120.114
    255.255.120.115
    255.255.120.118
    255.255.120.120.......
```

Comment: All of them start with "255.255.120."?

Comment: String manipulation is often better done in the calling program, not in the SQL Server (that doesn't have very strong string manipulation methods)

Comment: Please don't make your example based on something that happens some times. Add examples that cover all cases.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because shows no effort. Just asking others to write code.

Comment: @ Deepanshu Kalra, yes It is fixed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IPAddress EX:'255.255.120.110-255.255.120.115,255.10.120.110-255.10.120.115,255.10.10.115'

```
insert into #IPAddresses(ColumnName)
        select * from [dbo].[splitFunction] (@IPAddresses,',')

        declare @IPStart int

        declare Cur_IPAddress cursor for 
        select substring(substring(Item, charindex('.', Item, charindex('.', Item, charindex('.', Item ) + 1) + 1)+1, len(Item)),1,
                charindex('-',substring(Item, charindex('.', Item, charindex('.', Item, charindex('.', Item ) + 1) + 1)+1, len(Item)))-1) IPStart ,
                substring(Item,1, charindex('.', Item, charindex('.', Item, charindex('.', Item ) + 1) + 1)) IPExt,
                reverse(substring(reverse(Item),1,charindex('.',reverse(Item))-1)) MaxIp
        from  #IPAddresses where charindex('-',Item)>0
        open Cur_IPAddress  
        fetch next from  Cur_IPAddress into @IPStart, @IPExt, @MaxIp
        while @@fetch_status = 0
        begin
            ;with X 
            as(
                select @IPStart Lev
                union all
                select X.Lev+1
                from X 
                where X.Lev < @MaxIp
            )  insert into #IPAddresses
        select @IPExt +cast(Lev as varchar) Item  from X option(maxrecursion 1000)

        fetch next from  Cur_IPAddress into @IPStart, @IPExt, @MaxIp
        end
        close Cur_IPAddress
        deallocate Cur_IPAddress

        delete from  #IPAddresses where charindex( '-', Item )>0
        --select * from #IPAddresses
    end
```